# Change default TextFormField's icon color from grey to anything but show primary color on selection

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to change default colour of icon of TextFormField, which will also get changes on selection. There are few way to change colour but non of them works for me.

> **1.** Set icon color

When changing icon colour directly as below the icon colour will not change when selected, below is the code of the same and screenshot which shows red colour when field is selected or not selected.

```
     TextFormField(
        maxLength: 15,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "USER NAME",
          prefixIcon: IconTheme(data: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.redAccent
          ), child: Icon(Icons.email,))
        ),
        onSaved: (username) => _username = username,
      ),
```

[image]

> **2.** Leave it default

This will show grey colour when field is not selected and primary colour when field is selected. Below is the screenshot of the same. Here i want to change the colour of icon from grey to red and want to show primary colour on selection.

[image]

> NOTE:- It will be good if we can do this using theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below  will generate the `FocusNodes` you need to manage the focus of your `TextFormFields` and do a `setState` when the focus changes from one field to another. We are just creating a list of focus nodes, listening to changes on each of them and assigning them to a field:

```
List<FocusNode> _focusNodes = [
  FocusNode(),
  FocusNode(),
  FocusNode(),
  FocusNode(),
];

@override
void initState() {
  _focusNodes.forEach((node){
    node.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  });
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        focusNode: _focusNodes[0],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email,
            color: _focusNodes[0].hasFocus ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      TextFormField(
        focusNode: _focusNodes[1],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email,
            color: _focusNodes[1].hasFocus ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      TextFormField(
        focusNode: _focusNodes[2],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email,
            color: _focusNodes[2].hasFocus ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but is it possible to do the same thing using theme ?

Comment: I am using theme. The color of the icon will change base on your theme. If you want the unselected color to be also from the theme, just find the corresponding color within the theme options.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change icon color at the time textFormField is selected,
change it according to below.

```
...
            Theme(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    maxLength: 15,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "USER NAME",
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email,)
                    ),
                    onSaved: (username) => _username = username,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    maxLength: 15,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "EMAIL",
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email,)
                    ),
                    onSaved: (usermail) => _useremail = usermail,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              data: Theme.of(context)
                  .copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.redAccent,),
            ),
...
```

**Conclusion:**
Wrap all the textFormFields widgets with Theme widget and set **data** field as the color you want as a highlighter.

Comment: I want to change that default grey colour(when textfield is not selected) to something else but want to remain the primary colour on selection.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the picture below, You can't change the default color of Icons in `Textfields`. The only solution for it is to create PR on flutter and change this method.

[image]